# A metrics to see reads/writes per shard elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch - 6.1.1
We have we have 650TB data, 9000+ shards
avg write TPS - 1300 per second
avg read TPS - 2500 per second

**Questions**

1. Can I introduce a new metric to see number of reads & writes per shard & per host.
   This is to track hot shards in our cluster. Currently I don't an option to add this.?
2. For reads is it right to assume that read goes to all the shards if we don't give the key, searches on an indexed field.

Thanks
Nisar

Answer (score 1):

With the following command you can get the read/write metrics per index/shard. it also gives you information about the active threads:

```
GET _nodes/stats?level=shards&filter_path=**.indices.**.*current,**.name,**.thread_pool.*.active
```

Regarding your second question, without routing, ES will pick a set of shards (primary and/or replicas) that are most likely to answer promptly, it's called [adaptive replica selection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search.html#search-adaptive-replica).

Comment: This metric is useful. This metric is for last x minutes or from the beginning of the cluster?